# Is there a one-liner closure function in Python?

Tags: python

I've been making good use of this function that usually define anytime I need because it's so small:

```
def func(_lambda, *args):
    return _lambda(*args)
```

i.e.

```
[func((lambda x: (("fizbuz" if x%5==0 else "fiz")
    if x%3==0 else ("buz" if x%5==0 else x))), x)
    for x in list(range(1,101))]
```

Is there a built-in equivalent function to this in Python?

Comment: There was one, once: `apply ` was deprecated in Python 2.3 and removed from Python 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at `functools.partial` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial)).

Broadly, you're looking at something like this:

```
from functools import partial

def func(*args):
    # your logic here

myfunc = partial(func, *args)
```

It's possible to pass additional arguments to `myfunc`, if needed; the example from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) demonstrates this well:

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> basetwo = partial(int, base=2)
>>> basetwo('10010')
18
```

None of this is necessary for your case, since moving your fizzbuzz logic out of the list comprehension and into a separate function allows you to use it like this (which, in my opinion, is much easier to follow):

```
[fizzbuzz(x) for x in range(1, 101)]
```

(The partial is a handy trick to have up your sleeve though.)

Answer (score 2):

Python 3 no longer has an apply function (though Python 2 did).

The list comprehension eliminates the need for this use of the function. Just use the body of the function directly.

```
[("fizbuz" if x%5 == 0 else "fiz") 
 if x%3 == 0
 else ("buz" if x%5 == 0 else x)
   for x in list(range(1,101))]
```

This is also more efficient, as you are no longer repeated calling a user-defined function.